# Dynamically change an onclick event to a new function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How do I dynamically change an `onclick` event to a new function? Here is the example:

```
<img name="space1" id="space1" src="images/8001.jpg" height="150 px" onclick="lrgWithInfo('1')" />
```

Here is what isn't working. All I want to change is the value passed.

```
document.getElementById("space1").onclick = lrgWithInfo('13');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("space1").onclick = lrgWithInfo('13');
```

This assigns the output of lrgWithInfo('13'); to you on click function. You could try

```
document.getElementById("space1").onclick = function () { lrgWithInfo('13'); };
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank-you so very much for your help!!

It worked, and although I tried using a new function I may not have added the semi colan inside the brackets. I never would have noticed that on my own.

Thanks again, project worked, and I will be back with a million more questions.

You rock!

kim